# Migration of Win OS between two blade servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, migration, operating-system, blade-server

Hi we have a Physical or blade server where we have installed win server 2008. It's configuration has 256Gb RAM. I wanted to know can we migrate the existing server along with OS to another server which has 512Gb RAM.or do we need to build the 512Gb server from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: If the hardware is pretty much the same except the RAM, you can swap the drives. Why not just add the RAM into the current one?

Comment: If this were a boot from SAN Cisco UCS blade, I'd say just reassociate the service profile with the new blade. :)

Comment: I think if we try to add the RAM it might void warranty and also the server should be compatible to accommodate additional 256GB RAM.

Comment: Adding RAM would void warranty... and moving the system to different hardware would not?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two servers have the same (or very similar) hardware, you can move the disk(s) from the first server to the second one, and Windows will probably boot without problems; but if the hardware is different (especially the disk controller) then Windows could be unable to boot at all.

Comment: Oh ok then we will have to check whether both the servers have IDE or SATA

Comment: This is not about IDE or SATA... even if the disks can be physically connected to the new server (which is of course a prerequisite), a different disk controller could still render Windows unbootable due to a boot driver mismatch. The hardware has to be really similar, if not identical.